# Post form data to Call back URL in Suite CRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have created few custom fields under Case like:

**Fields:**

```
ESN Number
Order Id
Product name
CallBack URL
```

In Call back URL field, i have something like:

```
{url : "abc.com", requestBody :"<some params>"}
```

On Click of save button, All the field's value must be passed/posted on the URL specified in 'CallBack URL' field.

I have my logic_hook.php like:

```
$hook_array['after_save'][] = array(
    2, //Integer
    'CPE Closed URL callback', //String
    'custom/modules/Cases/TestClass.php', //String or null if using namespaces
    'TestClass', //String
    'methodName', //String
);
```

**in TestClass.php**

**UPDATED**  :  I tried something like this, to post the form data to my local URL.

```
<?php
if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

class TestClass
{
    protected static $fetchedRow = array();
    function methodName($bean, $event, $arguments)
    {

        if($bean->fetched_row['type']=='CPE' && $bean->fetched_row['state'] == 'Closed'){
        //$json_call_back_url=$bean->callback_url_c;
        $json_call_back_url='https://httpbin.org/get';
        echo '<pre>'.print_r('ESN number:'.$bean->esn_number_c.'<br>'.'Order ID:'.$bean->order_id_c.'<br>'.'Product Name:'.$bean->product_name_c);
        
        print_r(json_decode($json_call_back_url, true));

        $myvars = ['product-info' => $bean->esn_number_c . '<br>' . $bean->order_id_c . '<br>' . $bean->product_name_c];
        $ch = curl_init( $json_call_back_url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        
        $response = curl_exec( $ch );
        var_dump($_POST['product-info']);
        print_r('Res:'.$_POST['product-info']);die;
       //die;
      }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED OUTPUT:**

> ESN number:123
>
> Order ID:1232121212
>
> Product Name:test
>
> 1
>
> D:\Ampps\www\Suite_dev\custom\modules\Cases\TestClass.php:47:null
>
> Res:

But I don't get any response.

AS of now, I get only the values entered from the fields, but I need to post those values to the URL.

Comment: anything in php error log? do you have php-curl installed? can you log the incoming request on the other side?

Comment: No error log, yes curl is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass `$json_call_back_url` into `curl_init` make sure it is actually a URL (`http://example.com`) not a json. Your code `print_r(json_decode($json_call_back_url, true));` makes me feel it is still `json`. Also when you send `$myvars` use associative array:

```
$myvars = ['product-info' => $bean->esn_number_c . '<br>' . $bean->order_id_c . '<br>' . $bean->product_name_c];
```

On the receiving side dump the post `var_dump($_POST['product-info']);` it should contain the product info.

**UPDATE:**

I wasn't probably clear enough. Since you are posting to `https://httpbin.org/get` (receiving side), you can't control it. You can only do `var_dump($_POST['product-info']);` on the receiving side you can control. Try this:

```
class TestClass
{
    protected static $fetchedRow = array();
    function methodName($bean, $event, $arguments)
    {

        if($bean->fetched_row['type']=='CPE' && $bean->fetched_row['state'] == 'Closed'){
            //$json_call_back_url=$bean->callback_url_c;
            $json_call_back_url='https://httpbin.org/get';
            echo '<pre>'.print_r('ESN number:'.$bean->esn_number_c.'<br>'.'Order ID:'.$bean->order_id_c.'<br>'.'Product Name:'.$bean->product_name_c);

            $myvars = ['product-info' => $bean->esn_number_c . '<br>' . $bean->order_id_c . '<br>' . $bean->product_name_c];
            $ch = curl_init( $json_call_back_url );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            $response = curl_exec( $ch );
            var_dump($response);

            // Check if any error occurred
            if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
                $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
                var_dump($info);
            } else {
                echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
            }

            curl_close( $ch );


        }
    }
}
```

See if you get any errors or additional info.

Comment: Have updated the $json_call_back_url to some test URL(Tried also with just for testing: www.google.com) and updated the $myvars as shown into an array kind...Im getting null as response

Comment: ok @zstate, there was a curl SSL certificate issue, i have added it and seems i get response as of now. Thanks